# sqlite duplicate column header on select

Tags: sqlite

I noticed that when you do a select like this :

```
select * from table1 join table2
```

If both tables happened to have a column with the same name, sqlite simply shows two columns with that name. For example if both tables have an id column, in the result you will get two identical column header.
This behaviour causing problems when working with jdbc, as you cannot get the value of the column.
Is there a generic way to overcome this. For example make sqlite give a prefix to these columns, or simply refuse to execute the query.

Comment: Why not just correctly join and put all column you want to select in the query?

Comment: Prefix the column names by the table name. I.e.: `table1.column1, table2.column1`...